# python: regex - catch variable number of groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
TABLE_ENTRY.0[hex_number]= <FIELD_1=hex_number, FIELD_2=hex_number..FIELD_X=hex>
TABLE_ENTRY.1[hex_number]= <FIELD_1=hex_number, FIELD_2=hex_number..FIELD_Y=hex>
```

number of fields is unknown and varies from entry to entry, I want to capture
each entry separately with all of its fields and their values.

I came up with:

```
([A-Z_0-9\.]+\[0x[0-9]+\]=)(0x[0-9]+|0):\s+<(([A-Z_0-9]+)=(0x[0-9]+|0))
```

which matches the table entry and the first field, but I dont know how to account for variable number of fields.

for input:

```
ENTRY_0[0x130]=0: <FIELD_0=0, FIELD_1=0x140... FIELD_2=0xff3>
```

output should be:

```
ENTRY 0:
        FIELD_0=0
        FIELD_1=0x140
        FIELD_2=ff3
ENTRY 1:
        ...
```

Comment: What is the final output you seek?

Comment: put an example in the question

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? The text in your question seems to be a kind of syntax description, not an example, right?

Comment: Are your sure about the `0x[0-9]+` - part of your regexp? Since that should be a hex number I would prefer `0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, it's impossible to do all of this in the `re` engine. You cannot generate more groups dynamically. It will all put it in one group. You should re-parse the results like so:

```
import re
input_str = ("TABLE_ENTRY.0[0x1234]= <FIELD_1=0x1234, FIELD_2=0x1234, FIELD_3=0x1234>\n"
             "TABLE_ENTRY.1[0x1235]= <FIELD_1=0x1235, FIELD_2=0x1235, FIELD_3=0x1235>")
results = {}
for match in re.finditer(r"([A-Z_0-9\.]+\[0x[0-9A-F]+\])=\s+<([^>]*)>", input_str):
    fields = match.group(2).split(", ")
    results[match.group(1)] = dict(f.split("=") for f in fields)

>>> results
{'TABLE_ENTRY.0[0x1234]': {'FIELD_2': '0x1234', 'FIELD_1': '0x1234', 'FIELD_3': '0x1234'}, 'TABLE_ENTRY.1[0x1235]': {'FIELD_2': '0x1235', 'FIELD_1': '0x1235', 'FIELD_3': '0x1235'}}
```

The output will just be a large dict consisting of a table entry, to a dict of it's fields.

It's also rather convinient as you may do this:

```
>>> results["TABLE_ENTRY.0[0x1234]"]["FIELD_2"]
'0x1234'
```

I personally suggest stripping off "TABLE_ENTRY" as it's repetative but as you wish.

Comment: everyday I rediscover how effortless python is, thank you.

Comment: if I remove the new line from the input string it doesn't capture 2 matches anymore, why is that? I get: ('TABLE_ENTRY.0', '0x3242', 'FIELD_1=0x1234, FIELD_2=0x1234, FIELD_3=0x1234>TABLE_ENTRY.1[0x1235]=0x98789: <FIELD_1=0x1235, FIELD_2=0x1235, FIELD_3=0x1235')

Comment: should be \s+<([^>]*)> instead of \s+<(.*)>

Comment: Fixed. Keep in mind your original specification was with `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a capture group for match unfit lengths:

```
([A-Z_0-9\.]+\[0x[0-9]+\]=)\s+<(([A-Z_0-9]+)=(0x[0-9]+|0),\s?)*([A-Z_0-9]+)=(0x[0-9]+|0)
```

The following part matches every number of fields with trailing comma and whitespace

```
(([A-Z_0-9]+)=(0x[0-9]+|0),\s?)*
```

And `([A-Z_0-9]+)=(0x[0-9]+|0)` will match the latest field.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gP3oO6/1

Note: If you don't want some groups you better to use non-capturing groups by adding `?:` at the leading of capture groups.(`(?: ...)`), and note that `(0x[0-9]+|0):\s+` as extra in your regex (based on your input pattern)